# Angular 10 decorators with IVY

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a component that looks like this:

```
export abstract class CrudAddEditComponent<U extends DomainObject, T extends BaseService<U>>
  extends SimpleComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {


constructor(messageService: MessageService,
                        protected service: T,
                        protected route: ActivatedRoute,
                        logger: NGXLogger) {
    super(messageService, logger);
  }
```

with the new decorator requirement what should I use on this class?

@Directive doesn't work because I get "Uncaught Error: Directives cannot inherit Components"

If I use @Component( {template: ''} ) I run into issues with my generics:

```
src/app/shared/components/base.components.ts:175:35 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'service' of class 'CrudAddEditComponent'.
      Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.
```

How do I decorate an abstract class that uses lifecycle methods like OnInit and extends another class with Generics?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, one of the parent classes didn't have the @Directive decorator, so I made sure everything up the food chain used @Directive() and they I was good to go.

```
@Directive()
export abstract class CrudAddEditComponent<U extends DomainObject, T extends BaseService<U>>
  extends SimpleComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
```